# Implement ctrl+shift+MouseOver on a button in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism-6

I am trying to implement ctrl+shift+mouseover on a button in wpf, mvvm.
I am doing something like:

```
<Button.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+Shift" Command="{Binding KeyCommand}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
/>
</Button.InputBindings>
```

or something like:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseOverCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I am unable to get the required behavior as Mouse Gesture does not support "MouseEnter" event.
I was trying to implement in a way like:

```
Step 1.- Through keybinding setting a variable in the viewmodel.

Step 2.- Accessing that variable's value on MouseEnter and do whatever in the command.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? What should happen in case of Ctrl+Shift+MouseOver ?

Comment: Is MouseOver not a requirement for pressing a button? How could you press the button without mouseover? "Enter" key? What would be the difference?

Comment: Write a behavior where you check your Mouse event key modifiers.

Comment: I am binding a different command on Ctrl+Shift+LeftClick and a different command on Ctrl+Shift+MouseOver. Both commands are separate and used for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an [attached behaviour](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) that hooks up event handlers to the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeftButtonDown` events and check whether the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys are pressed by the time the events are raised, e.g.:

```
private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
        && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)))
    {
        TheCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to implement in pure MVVM way.

Comment: That's why I suggested that you should create an attached behaviour. That is pure MVVM. So what's your point?

Comment: If you don't know what an attached behaviour is, you should click in the link I supplied. It also sounds like you want to some more reading about MVVM...you won't solve this using input bindings and interaction triggers.